# dynamic array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Stuck in a situation where i tried different solution but didn't get any workaround what i want is:

```
$scope.list={"A":[],"B":[],"C":[],"D":[]}
```

this type of objects of array but its should be dynamic for example when i click button this function will be called:

```
AppendToList(data)
{
       $scope.list.push("E":data)//error
}
```

i want this E to be dynamic when ever i click the next object should be created automatically if I click next time it should become `{"A":[],"B":[],"C":[],"D":[],"E":[data]}`

Comment: It is not valid javascript; You can do `$scope.list["E"] = data`

Comment: `list` isn't an array so you can't `push` items into it. Also note that the order of the items isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try like this.

```
AppendToList(data)
{
       $scope.list["E"]=data;
}
```

Comment: but every time I want a dynamic list like next time is should be F

Comment: if i do something like this  $scope.list[data]=data; it is working thanks bro :p

Comment: AppendToList(data,key)
{
       $scope.list[key]=data;
}

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.list` is actually an object. To add a property you need to use `list.A` or `list["A"]`

```js
var list = {};
list["A"] = [1,2,3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function nextChar(c) {
    var i = (parseInt(c, 36) + 1 ) % 36;
    return (!i * 10 + i).toString(36);
}

AppendToList(data)
{
$scope.list[nextChar($scope.list[Object.keys($scope.list)[Object.keys($scope.list).length - 1]])]=data;
}
```

tested it and its working fine you have just to add condition id the list is empty of full

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to add new object as dynamic element

```js
  
   var key = "E";
    var value= { Result: 'Very Success' }
    var list = { "A": [], "B": [], "C": [], "D": [] };
    var splited = JSON.stringify(list).split('}');
    list = JSON.parse(splited[0] + ',"' + key +' ":'+ '[' + JSON.stringify(value)+ '] }')
    console.log(list);
```